# Unity: video is playing without sound (2017.3)

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, video-player

When using unity 2017.1 Video is played with sound. And audio without a video also played well.

When I upgrade to unity 2017.3 video is played without sound, while audio file without video is played well (sound is on).

**Edit:**

When building the application to windows sound is working.
The problem seems to appear only in editor.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Report it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After sending a bug to unity, they respond after a long time.

The solution was adding this line when assigning the Audio from Video to AudioSource to be played.

```
private VideoPlayer _videoPlayer;

.
.
.
.
.

    //Assign the Audio from Video to AudioSource to be played
    _videoPlayer.controlledAudioTrackCount = 1;             // <-- We have added this line. It tells video player that you will have one audio track playing in Unity AudioSource.
    _videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack(0, true);
    _videoPlayer.SetTargetAudioSource(0, _audioSource);
```

But still don't know why it is working without this line on previous versions (2017.2 for example)? and why it is also working without this line on exe build?

Comment: ty . It was weird... I was looking for solution for almost an hour

Comment: Unity said that they fixed it in 2018 version, but I didn't test it yet.